# Unable to build geth executable from go-ethereum source code

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a question regarding building geth executable from source code .

I am able to create the **geth executable for windows and linux machines , both 64 bit systems**.

How can i create the **geth executable for the windows and linux 32 bit systems on my 64 bit machines** ?

Comment: What error are you getting during the build?

Comment: My feeling is that this question should live on the GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just a general architecture-related/cross-compilation question, rather than an Ethereum-specific one.

Your 64-bit machines will attempt to build 64-bit binaries by default, so you need to tell them not to.

Without going into lots of detail here, have a look at the following Stack Overflow threads. (Note that these are Linux-only, so you'll need to poke around for Windows equivalents.)

For 32-bit Go compilation:

- [How can I build for linux 32-bit with go1.6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302211/how-can-i-build-for-linux-32-bit-with-go1-6-2)

For 32-bit C compilation:

- [How to Compile 32-bit Apps on 64-bit Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355436/how-to-compile-32-bit-apps-on-64-bit-ubuntu)

Having said all this, if you're building 32-bit binaries, which you plan to run on 32-bit machines, then it might be easier just to get access to those machines and build there...

Also note that 32-bit vanilla binaries are available from the official [Downloads](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/) page, so if you're not making any code changes, it would be easier just to download the pre-built binaries. (I'll assume you *are* making code changes.)

Answer (score 1):

For build of Geth on the Ubuntu 64 bit  system you can proceed as below ( https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu )

Clone the repository to a directory of your choosing:

- git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
- Install latest distribution of Go (v1.7) if you don't have it already:

  (procedure for go-lang installation https://github.com/ethereum/go-
  ethereum/wiki/Installing-Go#ubuntu-1404)
- Building geth requires Go and C compilers to be installed:

  sudo apt-get install -y build-essential golang
- Finally, build the geth program using the following command.

  cd go-ethereum

  make geth ( or run make all to build every thing )